# Should Unnecessary edits be stopped?

Tags: discussion

I have recently observed edits being made in a puzzle, which make no contribution to the puzzle as a whole but are made only to style it. I mentioned [a recent example](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35303612#35303612) in The Sphinx Lair, The official Chatroom of PSE.

Low rep users can make earn +2 rep for each edit that they suggest and which is accepted. As a bonus to this, the edited question is bumped to the top making it more likely to be seen by people and hence upvoted/downvoted.

Now, Anyone can easily rollback the edits if it doesn't help much but that is not a great idea since that too bumps it to the top.

## **Should edits which are done just to change the fonts/to style text be stopped?**

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with edits to format or style text, especially on your own puzzle.

If the edits don't make the resulting post any easier to read, they should be rejected in the suggestion queue; this obviously doesn't apply to self-edits as they bypass the queue.

If there are an inordinate number of minor edits to a single post (as in the linked case, these will usually be self-edits) it may be appropriate to leave a comment politely requesting that the user dampen their editing enthusiasm.

Rolling back the edits seems entirely unwarranted, that doesn't put the question back into a superior state, doesn't shorten the revision history, and feels mean-spirited on the face.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and thats down to the community.

We can't prevent low-rep users from editing their own puzzles, we can rollback but as you said that still puts it top of the active list.

However if a user makes an edit on another users post which contributes nothing, then I trust the community to click the 'Reject' button and click

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Comment: If you all want, we can start watching the review queues for people who systemically approve minor edits.